# CSS3 Animations - Move Left on class add not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently looking in to and learning how to properly do CSS3 Animations and I've run in to a bit of trouble. I have a box currently sitting in the horizontal center of the page, and I'd like to have it move to the left with a transition when a class is applied to it.

characterBox is already attached to the div when the page loads. When I add characterActive to the div with jQuery though, it moves directly to the left without the transition. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

```
.characterActive {
    left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}
.characterBox {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
/* Sit Horizontally */
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Move the transition stuff to a class that is applied before you add characterActive

Comment: I've updated my answer to what you've said, but it still moves instantly without any transition. Kinda lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are switching from static to absolute positioning by adding that class, which is ok, but there's nothing to transition from because the `left` value from the static element is `auto` (transitions from/to automatic values are not reliable, see [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=571344))

So add:

```
.characterBox{
  left: 0px;
}
```

Also you have to switch the order of the definitions, because your 2nd `left` rule would override the first (http://jsfiddle.net/yLgkK/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that it doesnt work with the property `left`. try to use `margin-left` instead.